# buttons show locations differently by phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

As can be seen from the pictures below, why are the buttons in different places in other phones

can you help me with this

I want the buttons to be in the same place on every phone. (like the first picture)

My phone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5A6j.jpg)

my friends phone (huwai)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUo3.jpg)

My friends phone (samsung)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBlb.jpg)

The codes I use are below. How do I make changes to these codes will fix this problem? I don't know much about coding

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:text="Değiştir"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:onClick="random"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Kopyala"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="kopyala"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Paylaş"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="paylas"/>

    
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:text="Değiştir"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buttonCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:onClick="random"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCenter"
        android:text="Paylaş"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/buttonLeft"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buttonRight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:onClick="paylas"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/buttonCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Kopyala"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="kopyala"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't foget adding to build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

Comment: unfortunately does not support this. I'm doing it from the phone apk. : constrainlayout

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways
the best way is use linear layout horizontal and set weight =1 for every button.
And i suggest you use sdp instead of dp for margin , padding and ...
You can find it in github just search sdp.

Comment: I will look. What is the difference between dp and sdp?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp this is the link , explanation : An android lib that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.
and of course as i said before weight is the best solution.

Comment: pls choose best answer if my solution worked for you.